# Bitwise and image resolution calculation in python. Can someone explain the code?

Tags: python, bit-shift

```
with open("image.jpg",'rb') as file:
    file.seek(163)
    a = file.read(2)
    height = (a[0] << 8) - a[1]
    a = file.read(2)
    width = (a[0] << 8) - a[1]
print(str(height) + " x " + str(width))
```

I am still learning python. I know bitwise operators leftshift and rightshift. But I don't understand this code.

What I understand is:

1. We open the image with binary reading as file.
2. Move the cursor to 163 with `file.seek()`. Why 163?
3. Read the file with size of 2 bytes. Why?

I don't understand the 4th line and 6th line at all. Print function is okay.

I tried with Pillow and cv2. But in case, I can't work with those modules, I think I should know this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's crude and ugly but reading `SOF0` which contains image height and width, see near the end of [this](https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/2017-01-31_jpeg/) article. It is actually incorrect too. It should be:

```
with open("image.jpg",'rb') as file:
   file.seek(163)
   a = file.read(2)
   height = (a[0] << 8) | a[1]     # It should be ORed in not subtracted
   print(height)
   a = file.read(2)
   width = (a[0] << 8)  | a[1]     # It should be ORed in not subtracted
   print(width)
```

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) entry on JPEG.

---

As a mini example, let's make a 640x480 red JPEG with **ImageMagick**:

```
magick -size 640x480 xc:red image.jpg
```

Now let's look for the `SOF0` marker which is `FF C0`:

```
xxd -c16 -g1 -u image.jpg | grep -A2 "FF C0"
00000090: 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 FF C0  ................
000000a0: 00 11 08 01 E0 02 80 03 01 11 00 02 11 01 03 11  ................
000000b0: 01 FF C4 00 15 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

If we check what 640 and 480 look like in hex:

```
printf "%x %x" 480 640
1e0 280
```

and you can see them at offset 163 into the file, because offset `a0` is 160 and we are 3 bytes on from that.

Comment: Good answer.  One note, the Wikipedia link has a trailing / which makes Wikipedia try to go to a non-existent article on "JPEG/"

Comment: So, the resolution is always stored at 163 place. Thank you. I am curiouser. How do you change an image into those numbers? Teach me!

Comment: It's not actually very good practice to assume that. It is better to use a proper, tested library that can do it for you flexibly and correctly for all image types and variants, e.g. **PIL/Pillow**, or **OpenCV** or **imageio** or **wand**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is that code in plain language:

1. Open the image.jpg file in read mode as a binary as variable 'file'
2. Move the cursor to 163 (to get to where the size is stored for Frame 0 (part of the internals of a JPEG file, not necessarily always in that position))
3. Read the 2 bytes that store the height into variable a
4. Get the height by left shifting the first byte by 8 places and left then subtracting the second byte (note this doesn't give the correct answer, the - should be an | instead)
5. Read the 2 bytes that store the width into variable a
6. Get the width by left shifting the first byte by 8 places and then subtracting the second byte (note this doesn't give the correct answer, the - should be an | instead)
7. Print the height and width as strings in 'height x width' format

There is a good writeup on decoding JPEG here [1](https://yasoob.me/posts/understanding-and-writing-jpeg-decoder-in-python/)

Comment: This helps me understand that line 4 and 6 are just using to change binary to decimal with bitwise operators. <a href=“https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/73272/binary-to-decimal-using-bitwise-operators”>This </a> said we can’t change binary to decimal with bitwise operators. Can u show me with example codes? I tied my line 4 code. It was error.

Comment: I was wrong about what was going on there.  They left shifted 8 to make one longer number and then subtracted where they should have used | to or in the bits of a[1]. So if a[0] was in binary 11111111, they move it 8 bits over to be 1111111100000000 then or in the a[1] value over those new 0's.  The binary to decimal conversion happens at the print statement.